# fopen() fails, results in errno=10553 - "connection was aborted"

Tags: php, fopen

when I use fopen() on my server files it works perfect but if i use some other url it doesn't!

this is how I used it (just in case):

```
<?php
$page = fopen("http://www.example.com/", "r");
...
?>
```

and this is what I get from the sever:

```
Notice: fopen(): send of 16 bytes failed with errno=10053 An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. in 

Notice: fopen(): send of 23 bytes failed with errno=10053 An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. in 

Notice: fopen(): send of 2 bytes failed with errno=10053 An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. in

Warning: fopen(http://www.example.com/): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in
```

all pointing to fopen(). (for privacy I omitted the path)

I searched with google and looked through php.net but I couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Is this on localhost?

Comment: Do you have command line access there, and can tools like `wget` or `curl` get the page, or are they having problems as well?

Comment: @HarryBeasant yes it's on localhost

Comment: Can you open that URL in your browser?

Comment: Did you search for `failed with errno=10053`? Software abort E.G a software firewall blocked it...

Comment: Is allow_url_fopen enabled in php.ini?

Comment: @PaoloNiccolòGiubelli yes I can. and I tried a lot of urls

Comment: @iBiryukov how do I do that?

Comment: Just open your php.ini config file and take a look. Print phpinfo() to see where your php.ini is.

Comment: @iBiryukov I checked and it is on

Comment: @PaoloNiccolòGiubelli I checked and it is on

Comment: Try use "b" (binary) instead of "t" (text)

Comment: @PaoloNiccolòGiubelli the same problem with both of them

Comment: Do you have SELINUX enabled on your system? http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php#56551

Comment: @PaoloNiccolòGiubelli I'm on windows.

Comment: Sometimes it's difficult to track which php.ini you are using. Consider do a var_dump(ini_get('allow_url_fopen')); to be sure your settings are good.

Comment: @PaoloNiccolòGiubelli this is what I got: string(1) "1"

Comment: I think it's something about timeout or a premature close of the socket. Try with this http://www.webmasterworld.com/php/3154615.htm and let me know!

Comment: @PaoloNiccolòGiubelli still the same problem. and the return value of fopen is bool(false). for every case

Comment: @Wrikken I tried curl and it works. but I'm more used to fopen so I hope you can help me with that. and one more question, does curl give the same handle as fopen? can i use fread(), fgets(), fseek()...?

Comment: @abdelkarim: I was just suggesting curl to see if it was general connectivity problem or just `fopen()` itself. General connectivity I'd know how to proceed, if `fopen()` itself does not work but curl does... I'm at a loss. (And no, curl won't give you a file descriptor, but if you want to change as little code as possible you could save the output in a temporary file & use all your calls on that file).

Comment: John Don had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31742685/an-established-connection-was-aborted-by-the-software-in-your-host-machine-windo) but then solved it.