# An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine Windows 8.1

Tags: php

I am trying to create an HTTP request to read the URL, and this code was working fine 15 days back, but now it's not working.

```
<?php
    $source_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/stepblogging';

    $rest_url = "http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=" . urlencode($source_url);
    $xml_response = file_get_contents($rest_url);
    $xml_record = simplexml_load_string($xml_response);

    $fb_share_count = $xml_record->link_stat->share_count;
    $fb_like_count = $xml_record->link_stat->like_count;
    $fb_comment_count = $xml_record->link_stat->comment_count;
    $fb_total = $xml_record->link_stat->total_count;
    echo 'Facebook Share:' . $fb_share_count . '<br/>';
    echo 'Facebook Like:' . $fb_like_count . '<br/>';
    echo 'Facebook Comment:' . $fb_comment_count . '<br/>';
```

After running this code, the output is:

> Notice: file_get_contents(): send of 103 bytes failed with errno=10053 An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. in E:\workspace\php\htdocs\connectivity\fbcount2.php on line 4
>
> Notice: file_get_contents(): send of 24 bytes failed with errno=10053 An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. in E:\workspace\php\htdocs\connectivity\fbcount2.php on line 4
>
> Notice: file_get_contents(): send of 2 bytes failed with errno=10053 An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. in E:\workspace\php\htdocs\connectivity\fbcount2.php on line 4

I am new to PHP. Please help me.

Comment: This I think is a [Windows Socket Error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Difficult to diagnose remotely

Comment: this error is coming due to this?? :-error code 0x80073712 or 80073712   http://www.thewindowsplanet.com/1957/how-to-fix-0x80073712-windows-update-error-in-windows-8-1.htm      https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/957310

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, I found the answer by my own. This error was because of the k9 software, so I uninstalled it, and now there is no error regarding connection establishing. If anyone is getting this error, he/she should uninstall the software such as Skype, k9 (protocol using software) type of software.

Comment: such a small world, I installed K9 software today while I was developing my php script, and I got that error. I'd never know in a million years what was the cause, until I found your answer. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: That solved my issue as well. But isn't there a way to keep K9 and still solve this issue?

Comment: i tried it by changing the localhost ip and all but nothing happened, i am trying to achieve that issue

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and it turned out that it wasn't my machine closing the connection but rather the server with which I was connected was kicking me due to an error in my code that spammed the site.

For anyone who has this issue, check that you aren't doing the same thing I was. If you think it's the server, it may be that the server is trying to handle too many requests all at once, not always from the same source.