# when check email address of yahoo domain it gives notice in php

Tags: php, html, email

Hi i have used the php script for email validations.The code is working if i check the email address of gmail domain it gives correct result and check email is valid or invalid email. but when i check the email address of yahoo domain it gives error  Notice: fwrite(): send of 6 bytes failed with errno=10053 An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.I want to avoid thie notice for yahoo address.

```
<div class="container" style="width:80%;margin:0 auto;">
  <h3>Email Validation Script</h3>
  <div class="form-group" >
    <form method="post">
    <label for="comment">Email Address</label>
<textarea class="form-control"  name="em" id="" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="please enter email addresses"></textarea >
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Check email addresses" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

```
require_once('smtp_validateEmail.class.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$em= $_POST['em'];
$emails2=substr(strrchr($em, "@"), 1);
//echo $emails2;
// if($emails2 == 'yahoo.com'){
//  echo "not valid";
// }
// else{
//  echo "valid";
// }
$emails1 = implode(",", preg_split("/[\s]+/", $em));

$emails = explode(',',$emails1);

//$emails = array('dave1@hmgamerica.com', 'babita@gmail.com');
// an optional sender
$sender = 'user@yourdomain.com';
// instantiate the class
$SMTP_Validator = new SMTP_validateEmail();
// turn on debugging if you want to view the SMTP transaction
$SMTP_Validator->debug = true;
// do the validation
$results = $SMTP_Validator->validate($emails, $sender);
echo "<div class='container' style='width:77%;margin:0 auto;background:#F0F0F0;'>";
    echo "<h3>List Of Emails</h3>";
// view results
foreach($results as $email=>$result) {
    if ($result) {

   echo "<div  style='color:green';>
     The email address  $email is  valid
     </div>";
     echo "<br>"; 
    //mail($email, 'Confirm Email', 'Please reply to this email to confirm', 'From:'.$sender."\r\n"); // send email
  } else {

    // echo "not valid";

    echo "<div style='color:red';>
     The email address  $email is invalid
     </div>";
     echo "<br>";

  }

}
echo "</div>";
}
```

?>
The error is line  fwrite($this->sock, $msg."\r\n");-

```
function send($msg) {
  fwrite($this->sock, $msg."\r\n");

  $reply = fread($this->sock, 2082);

 $this->debug(">>>\n$msg\n");
 $this->debug("<<<\n$reply");

  return $reply;
 }
```

Comment: Where is the send function called in the above code?  Aha it's in the validator: https://github.com/elliotttf/valid-mails/blob/master/smtp_validateEmail.class.php

Comment: yes it is a validator in php but when i check email address of yahoo domai it gives notice error and error is in send function if i comment this fwrite line then this code is not work .So please can you tell me the solution.

Comment: you are asking us to debug a mystical library.  How about including the link to the library/version that you have. `require_once('smtp_validateEmail.class.php');` isn't much to go on.  Have I linked correctly above?

Comment: Yes you have linked the file correctly above  and i have use this file in my script but it also gives me same error when i check email address of yahoo domain.

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: can you please explain what do you mean?

Comment: When I ask about your platform, I'm requesting information about your server environment:  Php version, host operating system etc.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look up your error code (errno 10053)?

It hints that you are on Windows and the socket is aborting.

Perhaps: [An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine Windows 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31742685/an-established-connection-was-aborted-by-the-software-in-your-host-machine-windo)

Did you try validating just one yahoo address with your library?

```
<?php 
$SMTP_Validator = new SMTP_validateEmail();
$SMTP_Validator->debug = true;
$results = $SMTP_Validator->validate(array('foo@yahoo.com'));
var_dump($results);
```

You could be having some socket problems. The lib code suggests that upon socket creation failure the domain will be skipped.  So it's as if the socket gets created but later there is a problem.

Try the following code in a separate file to see if you get any errors while connecting to a yahoo SMTP server:

```
<?php
if(getmxrr('yahoo.com', $mxhosts)) {
  $sock = fsockopen ($mxhosts[0], 25, $errno , $errstr);
  if(! $sock) {
      var_dump($errno);
      var_dump($errstr);
  } else {
      echo 'Socket created.';
  }
}
```

You could also replace the lib's fwrite line temporarily (and test for just one yahoo address).  This may indicate a time-out.

```
$meta = stream_get_meta_data($this->sock);
var_dump($meta);
die();
```

Comment: I have put this code in smtp_validateEmail.class.php page and i have comment this line fwrite($this->sock, $msg."\r\n");

  $reply = fread($this->sock, 2082);

 $this->debug(">>>\n$msg\n");
 $this->debug("<<<\n$reply");
  
  return $reply;  and then i tried to check email address of yahoo it gives me invalid address even this email is valid and  no notice is shown but when i tried to correct two emails of gmail and one email of yahoo it gives me all invalid email message which is not true.This message is due to comment of this code in it.  So please can you tell me whereto putthiscode.

Comment: fwrite and fget is the method that the code uses to talk to the remote smtp server.  By commenting out the fwrite, that conversation can't take place.  The validator code basically asks the remote server if an email address exists.

Comment: my script works in localhost but when i connect to server it did not work.It give me error like Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com:25 (Connection timed out) in and smtp_email_validate_class line no 155.I have searched this problem someone suggest that use other port number instead of 25 if i change the port no like 587 it also show same error  of fsockopen.So please cab you tell me the soluion of it.

Comment: @babi what do you mean your script works in localhost?  Which script?  Which server?  Why does it suddenly all work?  I thought you said your gmail lookups were fine.  You are changing the scope of your question.  You did not attempt to debug previously using my suggestions therefore I extinguish my offer of help.

Comment: I have solved my previous question which i have asked from you i.e i have used the error_reporting to prevent notice from it.Now I want to ask that this code works if i run this on localhost but when i put this code on web server it did not verify emails the code did not work.It give a error connection timeout error.So i was asking from do you know why this happens.The one cause is port no 25 might be blocked for outgoing server so it gives notice connection time out.Please help this.

Comment: I have used your code but i did not know how to use it